# header_checks is applied to mail body (CentOS 7 + Postfix 2.10.1)

Tags: email, postfix, spam-prevention, configuration-managment

I have received SPAM e-mail, added regular expression to header_checks about it and when tried to forward SPAM e-mail as attachment, then this check triggered and rejected my forwarded e-mail.

Regexp I've added is `/^From: spammer_name_and_partial_address/ REJECT Not accepting your SPAM`

In `main.cf` I have lines:
`header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks` for headers and
`body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks` for body tests.

I have controlled, that I have not added same regexp to body_checks.

Relevant log entry:
`Apr 20 11:33:22 myserver postfix/cleanup[22450]: 9F0356000C88B reject header From: spammer_name_and_address from my_ip_address; from=<my_email_address> to=<spam_database> proto=ESMTP helo=<my_laptop_name>: 5.7.1 Not accepting your SPAM`

I submit mail via submission port and as a password authenticated user.

How do I configure postfix to use header_checks for headers only and body_check for mail bodies only?